# Terminating hung Promises in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I have a javascript program that I would like to keep executing constantly by feeding an input from RabbitMQ. The problem is that it can occasionally hang indefinitely and block the whole execution. My initial idea was to use `Promise.race` to timeout after a specific period of time and let the next message in, but the broken Promise itself is still running somewhere in the background and never ends. In this design I will start generating "zombie" Promises that will eventually eat my system resources (since my app is running the whole time). I don't really have a control over this program. There is nothing like `abort()` function I can send to it. So my question is:
**Is there a way to kill the Promise and remove it from event loop completely?**

If it is not possible, then how about spawning second nodejs program as a child process and kill it if is something goes wrong? Will it properly clean my system resources?

Comment: Promises don't *run*.

Comment: A promise doesn't "run". It's the callback that's waiting for the input that's still around, and you must remove it when the timeout occurs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a way to kill the Promise and remove it from event loop completely?

No. Promises represent *the result* of an asynchronous task, they don't know about the task itself and thus cannot cancel it.

> If it is not possible, then how about spawning second nodejs program as a child process and kill it if is something goes wrong?

That would be an option, but spawning a process is a heavy operation as it needs its own runtime / memory / etc. so you shouldn't do that often.

Instead you can manage the [cancellation of the underlying asynchronous task](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortController/abort#Syntax). It depends on the actual task wether that is possible though.

Comment: Thanks @Jonas Wilms. In my case the program takes up to 30 seconds to finish so spawning a process should not influence performance

Answer (score 2):

You're focussing on the wrong part (understandably!). The *promise* isn't hung. The thing you're using the promise to observe is hung. Promises don't do anything, they just provide a means of *observing* something that's being done.

To resolve this problem, you need to look at what actions it is that are never completing, and then address the problem at that level. If the thing has some means of doing a cancel or abort, great; otherwise, time out the process at that deeper level and have it reject its promise.

> If it is not possible, then how about spawning second nodejs program as a child process and kill it if is something goes wrong? Will it properly clean my system resources?

Yes. It's more expensive, but that's the tradeoff. You can completely kill it if it hangs.